# Javascript XHR Post Request to php file: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, php, post, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to post formData to a php file.  I keep getting the following error"

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

The index.html file and the test.php file are located in the same directory.

I have tried moving the file to a different folder.
I have tried  ./  ../ http://localhost/... etc.

javascript

```
    const ctForm = document.getElementById('ctForm');

    ctForm.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();

        const data = new FormData(ctForm);

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open("POST", "test.php", true);

        xhr.send(data);
    })
```

html

```
    <form id="ctForm" class="contact-form">
        <label>Your info:</label>
        <div class="client-info">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="first name" required>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="last name" required>
            <input type="e-mail" name="email" placeholder="e-mail" required>
            <input type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="phone no" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Estimate Request">
            <textarea class="message" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea> 
        <button class="send" type="submit" value="Send">Send</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

test.php

```
    var_dump($_POST);
```

thanks in advance if you can help

Comment: What is the URL to access to `test.php`?

Comment: Have you tried to use `xhr.open("POST", "/test.php", true);` instead? We don't know where your test.php file is in comparison to the URL you are currently seeing the form.

Comment: @hppycoder I tried xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost/projectfolder/test.php",true)  and ..."/test.php" with the same result.  The test.php file is located in the project folder directory with the index.html file that contains the form.

Comment: In a normal browser have you been able to get test.php to work? Not with a AJAX post, not with anything else. Just normally getting it to load

Comment: yes.  it works.  I just can't get the AJAX code to work. My project can be changed to index.php and set the form action to test.php and it works but I really wanted to make the javascript work so I can stay on the page rather than navigate to a page then navigate back.  I am trying to to make the site with one index file, one js file, one css file and one php file.  I am going to use this AJAX code to run PHPMailer but I cant seem to get the simplest thing to work.  Frustrating.

Comment: I tried to use fetch() rather than AJAX but ran into the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using localhost, your URL string should be

`http://localhost/{project_folder_name}/test.php` instead of only `test.php` like below.

```
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost/{project_folder_name}/test.php");
```

you can ignore the third parameter, as it was stated in [mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open), third parameter is by default `true`

Comment: How would this help when OP needs to migrate to something other than localhost? What if localhost isn't open but `127.0.0.1:8000` is used instead? The relative URL pathing with `test.php` should work